# Case C: Euler's equation in Simmon's textbook

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Working through Simmons' Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes and we're stuck in Case C, page 360.

Case C: If x is missing from the function $f(x,y,y')$, then Euler's equation can be integrated to:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\,y'-f=c_1$$
This follows from the identity:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\,y'-f\right)=y'\left[\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\right)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right]-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$
The problem for us is what happens when we differentiate the left-hand side of the last result.
\begin{align*}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\,y'-f\right)
&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\,y'\right)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\\
&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\right)\,y'+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\,y''-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
\end{align*}

So we're not getting his result. Any thoughts?

So, with your comment suggestion, and the fact that $f$ is a function of $y$ and $y'$, we use the chain rule to write

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\frac{dy'}{dx},$$

or equivalently,

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,y'+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\,y''$$

Now, because $f$ is a function of $y$ and $y'$ only, $\partial{f}/\partial{x}=0$ and we get:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\,y''=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,y'$$

Substituting this above, we get, because $\partial f/\partial x=0$,

\begin{align*}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\,y'-f\right)
&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\,y'\right)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\\
&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\right)\,y'+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\,y''-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\\
&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\right)\,y'-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,y'-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\\
&=y'\left[\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\right)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right]
\end{align*}

Does this look correct?

Comment: Note that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} y'' = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} \frac{dy'}{dt}$$ and use the chain rule.

Comment: I've adjusted my work above to reflect what I learned from your comment. Am I understanding this properly?